# Gtest with C++11 std::condition_variable implies valgrind errors

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, googletest, googlemock

If I write a test with google test framework this way:

```
TEST_F( TestFName, TestName )
{
     std::condition_variable cv;
}
```

It generates a valgrind error. I run it with `--leak-check=full --track-origins=yes` options.

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17215==    at 0x4E3DA82: pthread_cond_destroy@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (pthread_cond_destroy.c:35)
...
 Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17215==    at 0x4551D0: TestFName_TestName_test::TestBody()
```

It was weird to realise that the error was from the `condition_variable cv` declaration. When I declared it global, the error dissapeared.

I am running Valgrind-3.7.0 on a machine with Ubuntu 3.8 x86_64.

Did someone else encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My wild guess, based on reading the source, is that your compilation environment does not match the environment used to compile the libstdc++ binaries you're using. Specifically, libstdc++ was compiled without `_GTHREAD_USE_COND_INIT_FUNC`, and it is defined in your environment.

Here is the reason: the header `<condition_variable>` defines a data member of a type which resolves to `pthread_cond_t`. If the macro `__GTHREAD_COND_INIT` is defined, the default initialization for this member is specified in the header, and the constructor is defaulted in the implementation file. If it's not, it is initialized with a function call in the body of a non-default constructor. Whether `__GTHREAD_COND_INIT` is defined is controlled by the `_GTHREAD_USE_COND_INIT_FUNC` macro.

If in-class member initialization is implemented in G++ the way I think it is, e.g. the in-class initializers are executed before calling the constructor, then the effect you see would occur when your libstdc++ was compiled with `_GTHREAD_USE_COND_INIT_FUNC` undefed, while right now it is defined in your environment somewhere. This means that the header does not provide in-class initialization and the default constructor from the library is used, leading to an uninitialized value.

Source references, in case you want to dig deeper:

- https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/condition_variable
- https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/condition_variable.cc
- https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr.h
- https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-posix.h

Comment: You have a very good point and for a minute I thought this would solve the problem. I #undef ed those symbols in my environment and the problem persists.

Comment: `#undef` won't do anything even if I'm correct, since those defines are pulled from `gthr-posix.h` which is included from `condition_variable`.

Comment: FWIW, on Ubuntu 13.10 with stock libstdc++ and g++ I cannot reproduce the problem - valgrind doesn't show any uninitialized values. Can you provide the output of `ldd test` where `test` is the test executable you've compiled? Maybe it's picking up some incompatible local libraries.

Comment: Will do, but I can not provide the output earlier than Monday because I will be offline for a while. Thanks

Comment: `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff195fe000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3da0561000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3da035d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3da0060000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d9fca0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3da0791000)
`

Comment: Hm, it seems that the C++ standard library is being statically linked. What is the command line you use to compile the test?

Comment: it is a big project and I use scons and a toolchain that uses g++ 4.6.3. I will try to reproduce it on a small project if you think that would be the problem